# background-image: url('img/bg-showcase-2.jpg');

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have tried some codes for `WordPress` but not working. please share any ideas about not working these codes.

```
background-image: url('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/bg-showcase-2.jpg');  

background-image: url('<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/bg-showcase-2.jpg');
```

Comment: background-image: url('<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/img/bg-showcase-2.jpg'); but not working

Comment: background-image: url('<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/bg-showcase-2.jpg'); this code also not working. Please share your experience.

Comment: Please share full code, Are you adding this as an inline style?

Comment: Where you want to use a Background image. In PHP file or CSS file?

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
background-image: url('img/bg-showcase-2.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

`background-image` needs `width` and `height` property set up. 
Example:

```
div {
background-image:url('/img/bg-show-case-2.jpg');
width:300px;
height:300px;
}
```